# Can protobuf data types be upgraded?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm new to Protobuf and so don't know if this is possible. If in a proto file I have a `fixed32` datatype, can I upgrade it to `fixed64` such that all *existing* `fixed32` values can also be read (i.e. backward compatibility) ?

If not, what's the best way to perform such an upgrade ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr Yes, but not with your exact types.**

You can move freely between varint-encoded types since they all use exactly the same encoding on the wire.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#updating):

> `int32`, `uint32`, `int64`, `uint64`, and `bool` are all compatible – this means you can change a field from one of these types to another without breaking forwards- or backwards-compatibility. If a number is parsed from the wire which doesn't fit in the corresponding type, you will get the same effect as if you had cast the number to that type in C++ (e.g. if a 64-bit number is read as an `int32`, it will be truncated to 32 bits).

Sadly, this does not apply to `fixed32` (which is only compatible with `sfixed32`) and `fixed64` (which is only compatible with `sfixed64`).

If you already have lots of data using the `fixed32` field, you'll have to create a new `int64` field and gradually transition from the existing field onto the new one (new code reads both fields but only populates the new one).